# How detect when lsp-mode has loaded a files references?

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm running into an awkward bug with `lsp-mode` + `clangd` for batch editing files.

When a source file is loaded, the symbols it points to aren't immediately available (using `xref-find-definitions` for example).

Calling `xref-find-definitions` fails on a newly loaded buffer.

Adding a sleep timer: e.g: `(sleep-for 3.0)` then calling `xref-find-definitions` works as expected (showing the header for an implementation of a function for example).

How can this be handled more reliably than sleeping and hoping the file references have loaded?

---

For reference

- This is a stand-alone, single-file script that uses emacs+lsp, with a `FIXME` comment around the sleep call.
  https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-relocate-docs
- [this-package](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-doc-show-inline) fails to work when the `doc-show-inline-idle-delay-init` is set to zero.

Comment: Try instead the function ```lsp-find-definition```, bounded to ```<s-l> gg``` - is that also slow? (without sleep).

Comment: All I get is this:
`LSP :: Connected to [clangd:57835/starting].
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method te...")
  error("The connected server(s) does not support method %s..." "textDocument/definition")
  lsp--send-request-async((:jsonrpc "2.0" :method "textDocument/definition" :params`
As wirh xref, calling`(sleep-for 3.0)` beforehand solves.

Comment: What ```lsp``` version do you have? Also, do you use cmake to have a ```compile_command.json``` file? Maybe posting some parts of your configuration will help. The ```lsp-mode``` uses part of xref core, not xref itself. A lag could be normal, until the file is indexed.

Comment: Use this: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide/ as guide - with the mention I do not use helm-xref.

Comment: In Emacs check the variable ```exec-path```- should contain ```clangd```'s path.

Comment: I have a very standard setup, Recent versions of all packages, using CMake with `compile_command.json` being found as expected, exec-path contains `clangd`, everything works, there is just a lag in indexing the file as far as I can see.

Comment: @ian re: `A lag could be normal, until the file is indexed.` -  so how can I tell if the file is indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs doesn’t index the file, the LSP server does (in this case that is clangd). The LSP protocol supports asynchronous notifications when results are available, so in principle clangd should be accepting your request and replying with a token that will identify the results when they are available. `lsp-mode` would then process the results as normal once it receives a notification with that token.

In the comments, you reported seeing these log messages:

```
LSP :: Connected to [clangd:57835/starting].
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method te...")
error("The connected server(s) does not support method %s..." "textDocument/definition")
lsp--send-request-async((:jsonrpc "2.0" :method "textDocument/definition" :params
```

This indicates that clangd has not advertised that it supports looking up definitions. Since it then starts working a few seconds later, this sounds like a bug in clangd. Or maybe clangd just doesn’t support this at all, and you’re falling back to some other xref backend, in which case the answer to your question has nothing to do with `lsp-mode` at all. You should check the value of `xref-backend-functions`.

Edit: if the problem is simply that your batch process is running before the connection to the LSP server is fully established, then use the `lsp-after-initialize-hook` hook to start it instead.

Comment: re: **This indicates that clangd has not advertised that it supports looking up definitions.** - in that case, can this be checked?

Comment: Yes. Run `M-x lsp-describe-session`. This will show you the capabilities of each LSP server that Emacs is connected to. Look for the `definitionProvider` capability.

Comment: Interesting, the `definitionProvider` is `t`, however this misses the point. All the capabilities I need are there, I just have no way *(as far as I know)* to check if they have been initialized yet or not for a given buffer in elisp (hence the arbitrary sleep which I would like to avoid). In short, there is a sleep-for command that should be replaced by a call to wait until the the lsp data is ready.

Comment: `lsp-after-initialize-hook` only runs for the session, not after loading new files - so it's not a reliable way to know if a file has it's symbols loaded for lsp.

Comment: The script you posted opens all files in the list first, and then starts processing them. Since it doesn’t wait for the LSP session to be established, it can easily finish opening them all before that happens. You need to wait for this event before you start doing any work.

Comment: Nevertheless, starting a session is separate from having symbols loaded for a single buffer - I might want to load a file (without having to preload everything) and knowing when that buffers symbols are loaded. I partly did this to workaround the problem noted in this question. (so only one sleep call is needed, not a sleep call before loading every file).

Comment: Added another reference to the OP, a separate package which suffers from the same problem and isn't preloading files before use.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The error message that you quoted indicates that you tried to look up a definition before the connection to the LSP server was fully established. You can load the files all in one go, but you need to wait on that hook to be called before you try to look anything up.

Comment: Even if the lsp server has started (I tried idling until the lsp-after-initialize-hook runs), I still run into the problem where loading a new buffer can't properly perform an xref lookup unless there is a call to sleep first.

Comment: Do you get the same error message in that case?